# I have the black screen after installing ati control center

Tags: drivers, ati, screen, catalyst

I am new to Ubuntu , and I tried to install the amd catalyst control center on Ubuntu 13.04 ,but after installing i can't do anything because it only shows me the black screen. What can I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try CTRL+ALT+F2, you'll get a terminal login screen and you can login with your user and password. If it works, then here you can uninstall the drivers.